# Text In Image Detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I'd like to be able to detect and recognize text in an image (such as in the example shown below).  I have tried many techniques such as Otsu thresholding, blob detection, filtering and general cleaning up of the image such as Gaussian Blur etc.  I have then fed the pre-processed image into OCR software in order to recognize the text, however the results are unsatisfactory as the appearance of the text in my scenario can vary a lot.

What are the best techniques other than those listed can I use to detect and recognise text in images?

I'm currently using the OpenCV library.

[image: Text In Image]

Comment: In your processing, can you know where the text could be more or less?

Comment: The text could be anywhere unfortunately.

Comment: ok, two more questions... text is going to be solid or as you shown (solid but a little bit gradiented) and one more... have you tried to equalize the channels?

Comment: The text is solid, I think its a little gradiented due to the quality of the uploaded image.  I have tried converting the colour to HSV, is that what you mean?

Comment: Are the size and font of the text also unconstrained?

Comment: Yes both unconstrained unfortunately :(

Comment: will the letters be of same color within a single text? you could try to segment by color, group contours of simular size and run ocr on each group.

Comment: I can't guarantee the letters will be the same size or Color unfortunately.

Comment: Are you including the vehicle registration plate in the text or just the contact details ? If you expect the text to contain an email address you could use template matching with an @ symbol

Comment: No just the contact details.  Yep template matching could definitely be an option on the @ symbol.  However I'd still like to read the  remaining contact details.  Thanks.

Comment: If you match the '@' template then you can extract HSV values and do filtering in a range to find matching pixels - unless of course all the characters are a different colour. Though even then you should be able to at least limit the search location within the image and look for homogenous coloured regions using e.g. SimpleBlobDetector